# Programmatically restore NuGet packages using a global cache folder

Tags: .net, nuget

I have some code that uses the *NuGet.Commands* library to restore a specified NuGet package to a target folder. When the restore is done the target folder will contain only the specified package as well as any dependency packages.

When the target folder is still empty, restoring the packages from scratch may take a while. As an optimization, I would like to have the package-restore operation use a global cache folder (like for example the standard global cache located at *c:\Users\[username]\.nuget\packages*).

Any ideas how to achieve this? Here is the code I am currently using to restore packages:

```
public static async Task RestoreAsync(PackageIdentity packageToRestore, string targetFolderPath)
{
    var packages = new[] { packageToRestore };

    var frameworkName = new FrameworkName(".NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0");
    var targetFramework = new NuGetFramework(frameworkName.Identifier, frameworkName.Version, string.Empty, new Version());
    var machineWideSettings = new MachineWideSettings();
    var defaultSettings = Settings.LoadDefaultSettings(null, null, machineWideSettings);

    using var sourceCacheContext = new SourceCacheContext();

    var restoreArgs = new RestoreArgs
    {
        AllowNoOp = true,
        CacheContext = sourceCacheContext,
        CachingSourceProvider = new CachingSourceProvider(new PackageSourceProvider(defaultSettings)),
        ConfigFile = null,
        DisableParallel = false,
        Runtimes = new HashSet<string>(),
        FallbackRuntimes = new HashSet<string>(),
        RequestProviders = new List<IRestoreRequestProvider>(),
        Sources = new List<string>(),
        GlobalPackagesFolder = null,
        HideWarningsAndErrors = false,
        Inputs = new List<string>(),
        IsLowercaseGlobalPackagesFolder = false,
        LockFileVersion = null,
        ValidateRuntimeAssets = null,
        Log = NullLogger.Instance,
        MachineWideSettings = machineWideSettings,
        PackageSaveMode = PackageSaveMode.Defaultv3
    };
    restoreArgs.PreLoadedRequestProviders.Add(
        new DependencyGraphSpecRequestProvider(
    new RestoreCommandProvidersCache(),
    GetDependencyGraph(packages)));

    var restoreSummary = await RestoreRunner.RunAsync(restoreArgs);

    var errors = restoreSummary.SelectMany(rs => rs.Errors);
    if (errors.Any())
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed restoring packages.",
            new AggregateException(errors.Select(e => new Exception(e.Message)).ToArray()));
    }


    DependencyGraphSpec GetDependencyGraph(IEnumerable<PackageIdentity> packages)
    {
        var dependencyGraphSpec = new DependencyGraphSpec();

        foreach (var package in packages)
        {
            VersionRange versionRange = new(package.Version);
            string uniqueName = $"{package.Id}-{targetFramework}-{versionRange.ToNormalizedString()}".ToLowerInvariant();
            string projectFilePath = Path.Combine(targetFolderPath, $"{package.Id}{package.Version}.csproj");
            var packageSpec = new PackageSpec
            {
                Name = uniqueName,
                FilePath = projectFilePath,
                Dependencies = { },
                TargetFrameworks =
            {
                new TargetFrameworkInformation
                {
                    TargetAlias = targetFramework!.GetShortFolderName(),
                    FrameworkName = targetFramework,
                    Dependencies =
                    {
                        new LibraryDependency
                        {
                            LibraryRange = new(package.Id, versionRange, LibraryDependencyTarget.Package)
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
                RestoreMetadata = new()
                {
                    ProjectStyle = ProjectStyle.PackageReference,
                    ProjectName = uniqueName,
                    ProjectUniqueName = uniqueName,
                    OutputPath = Path.Combine(targetFolderPath, ".restore", package.Id, package.Version.ToString()),
                    ProjectPath = projectFilePath,
                    PackagesPath = targetFolderPath,
                    FallbackFolders = { },
                    Sources = { new PackageSource("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json") },
                    OriginalTargetFrameworks = { targetFramework.GetShortFolderName() },
                    TargetFrameworks =
                {
                    new ProjectRestoreMetadataFrameworkInfo
                    {
                        TargetAlias = targetFramework.GetShortFolderName(),
                        FrameworkName = targetFramework
                    }
                },
                    ProjectWideWarningProperties = new WarningProperties()
                }
            };

            dependencyGraphSpec.AddProject(packageSpec);
            dependencyGraphSpec.AddRestore(packageSpec.Name);
        }

        return dependencyGraphSpec;
    }
}

internal class MachineWideSettings : IMachineWideSettings
{
    private readonly Lazy<ISettings> settings;

    public MachineWideSettings()
    {
        var baseDirectory = NuGetEnvironment.GetFolderPath(NuGetFolderPath.MachineWideConfigDirectory);
        this.settings = new Lazy<ISettings>(() => NuGet.Configuration.Settings.LoadMachineWideSettings(baseDirectory));
    }

    public ISettings Settings => this.settings.Value;
}
```

I tried specifying the `GlobalPackagesFolder` property to point at my "cache" folder, but this causes the packages to be restored into that folder instead.